# Faster way for find some value in matrix with matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, matrix, numbers

I have a matrix and I am trying to find where i getting a value. so, i am using `find(x==y)`for making vectors with the values, for example:

```
n11=find(x==11)
n4=find(x==4)
n8=find(x==8)
```

And n11, n4, n8 are not of the same length.

Sometimes, i have to do this like 20 or 30 times for 20 or 30 different values of x, so if for example i want to get an interval of x∈[1991,2015] `find(x==1991) to find(x==2015)` how can i get those values faster without doing

```
find(x==1991)
.
.
.
find(x==2015)
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/):

```
n= find(x>=1991 & x<=2015)
```

**EDIT**

`meshgrid` can be used to obtain a vector for each year:

```
x= [1991 1992 1991 2015 2016 1992 1988 1994]; % example data
[m,n]= meshgrid(x,1991:2015); % the second argument contains the years we need
n= (m==n);
```

Now `n(1,:)` is equal to `x==1991`, `n(2,:)` is equal to `x==1992` etc; `find(n(1,:))` equals `find(x==1991)` etc.

Comment: but i need a vector for each year.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a matrix for saved results. and use "for loop" for doing automaticly.

```
start=1991;
endi=2015;
for i=start:endi
    num_column=size(find(x==i),1)
    mat(i-start+1,1:num_column)=find(x==i);
end
```

In each row, we have result of one value ignoring zero numbers.